# Cannot compile mysql code

Tags: compiling, mysql

I have the following code

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

when i try to compile it using

```
gcc mysqldb.c -o mysql -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

i get an error saying fatal error mysql.h:No such file or directory. how can i successfully compile and run the code

Comment: For me this "just works" on Ubuntu 12.04. Please provide the output of `find /usr -name "mysql.h"` and `apt-cache policy libmysqlclient-dev`.

Comment: How exactly was the problem solved? Please give some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h` exists. If you have installed the [header files](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) somewhere else (say `/opt/mysql/include`), add that location with `-I/opt/mysql/include`.

Comment: am sorry if the question is lame but how do i check for that

Comment: @sosytee go to the directory /usr/include/mysql and search if the file mysql.h is founded

Comment: I have checked and it exists in /usr/include/mysql but the problem still remains

Answer (score 4):

Try compiling like this:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/mysql mysqldb.c -o mysql -lmysqlclient
```